# UITableView with UICollectionView in a row reusing the collection from the first row

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UITableView that has a UICollectionView in every cell.

The problem is that the table reuses the first cells data so it presents the first collection in the latest table cell...

UITableView code -

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tableCell", for: indexPath) as! ProjectTableViewCell

    if !didIndex{
        cell.i = i
        i += 1
        if i >= projects.count{
            i = 0
            didIndex = true
        }
    }

    return cell
}
```

And the UICollectionView within the UITableViewCell -

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    photosAsset = (PHAsset.fetchAssets(in: assetCollections[i], options: nil) as AnyObject!) as! PHFetchResult<AnyObject>!

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionCell", for: indexPath) as! ProjectsCollectionViewCell

    let asset: PHAsset = self.photosAsset[indexPath.item] as! PHAsset

    PHImageManager.default().requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: self.assetThumbnailSize, contentMode: .aspectFill, options: nil, resultHandler: {(result, info)in
        if result != nil {
            cell.imageView.image = result
        }
    })
    return cell
}
```

I checked the code, it looks like the result in the UICollectionView, cellForItemAt is ok, so I assume the problem is the reuse of cells in the table, trying to find a solution!

Thank you All!

**Solved**
I used indexPath.section

Comment: What are your trying to achieve with `if !didIndex{` etc?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't assign an index to a cell - this if very fragile. What happens if a cell is moved or deleted?

It looks like you're using `i` as an index in `assetCollections`, in which case why not…

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tableCell", for: indexPath) as! ProjectTableViewCell    
    cell.assetCollection = assetCollections[indexPath.section]
    return cell
}
```

and

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    photosAsset = (PHAsset.fetchAssets(in: assetCollection, options: nil) as AnyObject!) as! PHFetchResult<AnyObject>!

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionCell", for: indexPath) as! ProjectsCollectionViewCell

    let asset: PHAsset = self.photosAsset[indexPath.item] as! PHAsset

    PHImageManager.default().requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: self.assetThumbnailSize, contentMode: .aspectFill, options: nil, resultHandler: {(result, info)in
        if result != nil {
            cell.imageView.image = result
        }
    })
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Problem is the indexPath.row is always 0 because I have one row (for the collection) in each section

Comment: With i I’m trying to pass the section index

Comment: That was not clear from the question. In that case, just change to `cell.assetCollection = assetCollections[indexPath.section]`. Answer updated to reflect that.